# Extension of R packages

Tags: r

Suppose that I want to load some data for analysis in R. Let's take [this example](http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/nybirths.dat).

I have saved this file on my desktop using the extensions `.dat`, and then `.rdat`, and then used  function `load`. However, neither worked. It can't find the data.

Could you help me  figure out what to do?

I am new to the R language. which is why I can't understand why it does not work.

Should I use something to do with the directory as well - where I saved the file or what?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the directory.  Type ?setwd into the console.

Comment: how can i change  directori to  desktop?

Comment: You have to specify full path or set your setwd() to desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
X <- read.table("nybirths.dat")
```

or even:

```
X <- read.table("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/nybirths.dat")
```

And, btw, check out the documentation of `save` and `load` with `?save` and `?load`.